# How do you center a control in an MXML panel?

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, center

Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" backgroundColor="#ffffff">
    <mx:VBox percentHeight="100" percentWidth="100" >
        <mx:Image source="@Embed('img.png')" percentHeight="100" percentWidth="100"  />
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

How can I center the `mx:Image` in the `mx:Application`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Image` control is taking up the whole space, you want the [`horizontalAlign`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#style:horizontalAlign) and `verticalAlign` styles:

```
  <mx:Image source="@Embed('img.png')" 
            percentHeight="100" 
            percentWidth="100" 
            horizontalAlign="center" 
            verticalAlign="middle" />
```

If your image were less than 100% width, you might use the `horizontalCenter` and `verticalCenter` styles (equal to 0) instead or as well.